# Are Amazon's Provisioned IOPS a hard limit or guaranteed minimum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ebs, provisioned-iops

Are [Provisioned IOPS](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/fast-forward-provisioned-iops-ebs.html) a hard limit? Could IO spikes exceed the number of provisioned IOPS?

I couldn't easily find a definitive answer on the question. While I pretty much assume that it's enforced as a hard limit the documentation isn't very conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [published benchmarking results](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/ebs-provisioned-iops-some-interesting-resources.html) and some own testing it isn't possible to exceed the number of provisioned IOPS. This very much suggests a hard limit.

UPDATE:

I've just seen an RDS instance with 4000 provisioned IOPS getting around 4400 IOPS for about 20 minutes while concurrently importing dumps (few GB). Thus provisioned IOPS are not a hard limit. But still, although it's possible to exceed the provisioned limit it's probably not a good idea to expect that.